# new column value conditional on another column

Tags: r

I have list with many rows but one column; `107,114,142,143,146`. I would like to create another column depending on whether this has certain value, lets say `114`.

Looking at another post, I tried the following;

```
e_list$completed_forms <- rep(0, nrow(event_list))
e_list[e_list$e_list == 114, ][, "completed_forms"] <- "1"
```

Data list

```
structure(list(event_list = c("211,202,214,240,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,139,140,141,142,143,146", 
"211,202,214,240,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,121,139,140,141,142,143,146", 
"211,202,214,240,215,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,121,139,140,141,142,143,146", 
"211,202,214,240,215,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,121,139,140,141,142,143,146", 
"211,202,214,240,215,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,121,139,140,141,142,143,146", 
"211,202,214,240,215,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,121,139,140,141,142,143,146", 
"211,202,214,240,215,216,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,120,121,139,140,141,142,143,146", 
"211,202,214,240,215,216,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,120,121,139,140,141,142,143,146", 
"211,114,117,118,146", "211,104,114,117,118,121,146", "211,202,104,114,117,118,121,139,141,142,143,146", 
"211,202,214,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,121,139,141,142,143,146", 
"211,202,214,215,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,121,139,141,142,143,146", 
"211,202,214,215,216,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,120,121,139,141,142,143,146", 
"211,202,214,215,216,203,240,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,120,121,139,140,141,142,143,146", 
"", "211,114,117,118,146", "211,114,117,118,146", "211,104,114,117,118,121,146", 
"211,202,104,114,117,118,121,139,141,142,143,146", "211,202,214,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,121,139,141,142,143,146", 
"211,202,214,215,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,121,139,141,142,143,146", 
"211,202,214,215,216,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,120,121,139,141,142,143,146", 
"211,202,214,215,216,217,240,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,120,121,139,140,141,142,143,146", 
"211,202,214,215,216,217,240,203,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,120,121,122,139,140,141,142,143,146", 
"211,202,214,215,216,217,240,203,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,120,121,122,139,140,141,142,143,146", 
"211,202,214,215,216,217,240,203,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,120,121,122,139,140,141,142,143,146", 
"", "211,114,117,118,146", "211,114,117,118,146"), lead_completed_new_forms = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("event_list", "completed_forms"
), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

But I'm getting this error and I'm not sure why because I already added `0` to each column with the first line.

> Error in [<-.data.frame(*tmp*, , "completed_forms", value
>   = "1") :    replacement has 1 row, data has 0

Comment: can you post the `dput()` of your list or dataframe that you're talking about?

Comment: Please include an example of your data as mentioned above and note that `rep(0, nrow(event_list))` returns a numeric vector whereas ` <- "1"` is an attempt to fill elements of that vector with a character data type. Further, your use of two `[ ]` in a row is most likely unnecessary.

Comment: @lmo I didnt convert it into vector, would that be the problem?

Comment: @MattW. included in the post now.

Comment: I think it was cut off. It should start with `structure(...`

Comment: @MattW. So many lines in the list that I couldn't capture the first lines on the console

Comment: try `dput(head(event_list), 30)`

Comment: @MattW. ok perfect updated the original post now!

Comment: @EfeTuncel All set- lmk what you think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Whole Thing:**

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- as.data.frame(str_split_fixed(df$event_list, ",", max(length(strsplit(df$event_list, ",")))))

names(df2) <- paste0("event_", 1:ncol(df2))

df2$sequence <- paste0("seq_", 1:nrow(df2))

df3 <- df2 %>% 
      gather(event, event_num, -sequence) %>%
      replace(. == "", NA) %>%
      filter(!is.na(event_num)) %>%
      select(-event) %>%
      mutate(Count = 1) %>%
      spread(event_num, Count) %>%
      replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

**Broken Down:**

I would do a few things to clean up this dataset before tagging these. This will make it much easier to manipulate.

```
head(df)
                                                                   event_list completed_forms
1         211,202,214,240,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,139,140,141,142,143,146               0
2     211,202,214,240,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,121,139,140,141,142,143,146               0
3 211,202,214,240,215,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,121,139,140,141,142,143,146               0
4 211,202,214,240,215,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,121,139,140,141,142,143,146               0
5 211,202,214,240,215,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,121,139,140,141,142,143,146               0
6 211,202,214,240,215,104,105,106,107,114,117,118,121,139,140,141,142,143,146               0
```

I'm going to start by using `str_split_fixed` from the `stringr` package. If you don't have it, `install.packages(stringr)`.  This is going to turn our `dataframe` into a `matrix` so we will want to wrap it all in `as.data.frame()`.

```
library(stringr)

df2 <- as.data.frame(str_split_fixed(df$event_list, ",", max(length(strsplit(df$event_list, ",")))))
```

What this does is it takes a string like `"134, 444, 105, 106"` and splits it from one column into 4. The number of columns we'll have it split into is going to be the `max(length())`. That means if we have a column with 4 events, and one with 14, and another with 44 events, it will split every column into 44 columns to accommodate the largest one.

**Inspect:**

```
> head(df2)
   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27 V28 V29 V30
1 211 202 214 240 104 105 106 107 114 117 118 139 140 141 142 143 146                                                    
2 211 202 214 240 104 105 106 107 114 117 118 121 139 140 141 142 143 146                                                
3 211 202 214 240 215 104 105 106 107 114 117 118 121 139 140 141 142 143 146                                            
4 211 202 214 240 215 104 105 106 107 114 117 118 121 139 140 141 142 143 146                                            
5 211 202 214 240 215 104 105 106 107 114 117 118 121 139 140 141 142 143 146                                            
6 211 202 214 240 215 104 105 106 107 114 117 118 121 139 140 141 142 143 146
```

Lets clean up the headers by turning them into event numbers

```
names(df2) <- paste0("event_", 1:ncol(df2))
```

Now lets create a column to tag all of them which I'm going to call "sequence" for sequence of events.

```
df2$sequence <- paste0("seq_", 1:nrow(df2))
```

Now we want to move it from wide format to long format to digest easier. we can do this with the `gather` function in `tidyverse`. We also want to turn the blank spaces to `NA` values, and then remove them from the dataframe. *We also probably don't need the `event` column after this. I would then add a few more steps to turn it back into a grid where the column headers are the event number, and have a 1 or 0 like you asked.

```
library(tidyverse)

df3 <- df2 %>% 
      gather(event, event_num, -sequence) %>%
      replace(. == "", NA) %>%
      filter(!is.na(event_num)) %>%
      select(-event) %>%
      mutate(Count = 1) %>%
      spread(event_num, Count) %>%
      replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Great explanation. But I tried to split the data before using `str_split_fixed` and keep receiving the following error due to the data size; `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 74.5 Gb`

Comment: Try to clear your environment, have only the dataframe and use garbage cleaner `gc()`. That error usually means you have too much in memory. Try exiting rstudio and going back in.